# I'm trying to keep my csv files in monthly order like may, jun etc and trying to change the order with python, but unable to do that

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, sorting

**I'm trying to keep my csv files in monthly order like may, jun etc and trying to change the order with python, but unable to do that.**

My csv file names are jun01.csv, jun02.csv, jun03.csv, may03.csv, may04.csv. I want to change that according to monthly order like may03.csv, may04.csv, jun04.csv etc.

The code is below

```
import collections
import os

path = r'Stocks'
all_files = os.listdir(path)
filenames = []
for filename in all_files:
    if filename.endswith(".csv"):
        filenames.append(filename)

y = [z[:3] for z in filenames]


def lst(string):
    str1 = " "

    return str1.join(y)


print(lst(y))
------------------------------
Output is :
    
jun jun jun jun may may may may may may may may may may may may may may may may may may may may
------------------------------

# Code Continued


def rearrange(seq, order, keyfunc):
    if not isinstance(order, collections.Mapping):
        order = {v: i for i, v in enumerate(order)}
    return sorted(seq, key=lambda x: order[keyfunc(x)])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    filenames = lst(y).split()

    months = ['jan', 'feb', 'mar', 'apr', 'may', 'jun', 'jul',
              'aug', 'sep', 'oct', 'nov', 'dec']


    def get_month_name(filename):
        return filename.split(' ')


    for filename in rearrange(filenames, months, get_month_name):
        print(filename)
```

It's throwing error like :

```
File "C:month_sort.py", line 43, in <module>
    for filename in rearrange(filenames, months, get_month_name):
  File "C:month_sort.py", line 27, in rearrange
    return sorted(seq, key=lambda x: order[keyfunc(x)])
  File "C:month_sort.py", line 27, in <lambda>
    return sorted(seq, key=lambda x: order[keyfunc(x)])
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: Aside, `os.path.splitext()` is a more robust way to split filenames and extensions.

Comment: Where should i add this?

Comment: use yyyy_mm_dd.csv - much easier that way. not spelled out month names.

Comment: hey i posted an answer go check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is what you want but it sorts the file according to their months :

```
def rearrange(seq, order, keyfunc):
    if not isinstance(order, collections.Mapping):
        order = {v: i for i, v in enumerate(order)}
    return sorted(seq, key=lambda x: order[keyfunc(x)])


if __name__ == '__main__':

    months = ['jan', 'feb', 'mar', 'apr', 'may', 'jun', 'jul',
              'aug', 'sep', 'oct', 'nov', 'dec']


    def get_month_name(filename):
        return filename[:3]

    for filename in rearrange(filenames, months, get_month_name):
        print(filename)
```

Tell me if you wanted something else to happen

Answer (score 0):

Your `get_month_name` function is returning a list.
Try changing it to:

```
def get_month_name(filename):
    return filename.split(' ')[0]
```

This should work with the rest of your code unchanged.